# Issue installing a site package on Python 3.6.1

Tags: installation, python

I installed python on my desktop recently, selecting Python 3.6.1 using the WinPython-64bit-3.6.1.0Qt5 distribution. The installation happened smoothly. I then wanted to install a package called OpenPNM. I went to the console command prompt and did "pip install openpnm" which worked after a few attempts. The attempts had to be made as there were some permissions settings on my drive which had to be removed.

When I go into ..\WinPython-64bit-3.6.1.0Qt5\python-3.6.1.amd64\Lib\site-packages\ I do see the openpnm folder with everything in there. It seems like the installation worked correctly. However, when I try to import the package using import OpenPNM, it gives me an error. The error is as below:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "", line 1, in
>    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'OpenPNM'

Can someone suggest what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: From the command line, what are the results of `where python`? Also, is the name of the script you are trying to run `openpnm.py` or something similar?

Comment: Do you have 2 versions of Python installed on your device?

Comment: @Anaksunaman where python gives the following output: 

INFO: could not find files for the given pattern(s)

Comment: I am trying to install a package called openpnm; not calling a script.

Comment: @InfectedDrake Not that i know of. How can i check?

Answer (score 1):

The community standard for Python is for packages and their modules to be [`snake_case`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) (all lower case and underscores instead of spaces). So I would expect `import openpnm` to work.